# Python xml - remove spaces to get aligned xml document

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I have an MyXml.xml with structure:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tag1 atrib1='bla' atrib1='bla' atrib1='bla' atrib1='bla'>
    <tag2 atrib = 'something'>
        <tag3 atrib = 'something'>
           <tag4 atrib = '..'>
           </tag4>
        </tag3>
        <tag5 atrib = 'important'><div><h1>ContentFrom **OldXml.xml** </h1></div>
        ...
        </tag5>
    </tag2>
 </tag1>
```

Does anyone have idea how to make it to be in this form (to remove all spaces):

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tag1 atrib1='bla' atrib1='bla' atrib1='bla' atrib1='bla'>
<tag2 atrib = 'something'>
<tag3 atrib = 'something'>
<tag4 atrib = '..'>
<tag5 atrib = 'important'><div><h1>ContentFrom **OldXml.xml** </h1></div>
...
```

I have tried with this but won't work:

```
# Read in the file to a DOM data structure.
original_document = minidom.parse("MyXml.xml")

# Open a UTF-8 encoded file, because it's fairly standard for XML.
stripped_file = codecs.open("New_MyXml.xml", "w", encoding="utf8")

# Tell minidom to format the child text nodes without any extra whitespace.
original_document.writexml(stripped_file, indent="", addindent="", newl="")

stripped_file.close()
```

EDIT:

File is created through FOR loop in which elements are created, at the end this is how writing is done:

```
    dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(root))
    xml_string = dom.toprettyxml()
    part1, part2 = xml_string.split('?>')
    with open("MyXml.xml", 'w') as xfile:
          xfile.write(part1 + 'encoding=\"{}\"?>\n'.format(m_encoding) + part2)
          xfile.close()
```

EDIT newest code that prints whole doc in one line:

```
    dom = xml.dom.minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(root))
    xml_string = dom.toxml()
    part1, part2 = xml_string.split('?>')
    xmlstring = f'{part1} encoding="{m_encoding}"?>\n {part2}'
    with open("MyXml.xml", 'w') as xfile:
        for line in xmlstring.split("\n"):
          xfile.write(line.strip() + "\n")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you literally just want to strip whitespace, you don't need (or want) an xml parser at all:

```py
from pathlib import Path

inf = Path("my-input.xml")
with inf.open() as f, inf.with_name(f"stripped-{inf.name}").open("w") as g:
    for line in f:
        g.write(line.strip() + "\n")
```

Pathlib is just playing the role of `os.path`, `open`, etc here: you can rewrite without it if you happen not to like it (but `pathlib` is so vastly superior to munging text strings for paths I'm sure you wouldn't want to...)

If you do need to load with a parser, use exactly the same trick when it comes to writing, but iterate the parser object linewise.

---

Demonstration:

```py
from tempfile import TemporaryFile

data = """<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tag1 atrib1='bla' atrib1='bla' atrib1='bla' atrib1='bla'>
    <tag2 atrib = 'something'>
        <tag3 atrib = 'something'>
           <tag4 atrib = '..'>
           </tag4>
        </tag3>
        <tag5 atrib = 'important'><div><h1>ContentFrom **OldXml.xml** </h1></div>
        ...
        </tag5>
    </tag2>
 </tag1>"""

with TemporaryFile(mode="w+") as f, TemporaryFile(mode="w+") as g:
    f.write(data)
    f.seek(0)
    print("Before:")
    for line in f:
        print(line, end="")
        g.write(line.strip() + "\n")

    print("\n\nAfter:")
    g.seek(0)
    for line in g:
        print(line, end="")
```

### Edit:

<del>In your case there is a much simpler solution:  just don't use `toprettyxml` at all, use `toxml`.</del> (Update: apparently that renders with no linebreaks at all).  But even without that we can do the same thing:

```py
xml_string = dom.toprettyxml()
part1, part2 = xml_string.split('?>')
xmlstring = f'{part1} encoding="{m_encoding}"?>\n {part2}'
with open("MyXml.xml", 'w') as xfile:
    for line in xmlstring.split("\n"):
        xfile.write(line.strip() + "\n")
```

However I suspect `toprettyxml(indent="")` will do the same thing:

```py
xml_string = dom.toprettyxml(indent="")
...
with open("MyFile.xml", "w") as f:
    f.write(xml_string)
```

Comment: Thanks for quick RP, I have tried this solution but nothing happens with file

Comment: Exactly nothing with my file

Comment: Check my demo code works your end.  I really fail to see how strip() could *not* strip the line, but I'm certainly interested if there's an interesting failure mode your end.  Note that I did use *two* file names, rather than trying to modify in place (which is possible, but requires reading into ram first).

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to test this solution, having a hard time implementing to my file

Comment: Ah ok got it man, just tried and it works, just to figure out how to to implement this on my file. My file is generated through python script, but I do not see how that can impact? I just need at the end of creation of file, load file again, remove spaces and that is it, cause I need to import file into some external program which can read only that format... thanks man!

Comment: See edits; that might help.  If this did solve it, feel free to accept the answer :)

Comment: Sure I will, please see my edit, of how I write file at the end of FOR loop where elements are created

Comment: Now the code is in the original question I have edited the answer to address the issue directly :)

Comment: I feel we almost there, now prints whole doc in one line :D I ll put my code in edit

Comment: I ll update again, code that prints whole in one line

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237983/discussion-between-2e0byo-and-john).

Comment: After try of the last edit it works perfectly! Thanks a LOT man! I ll update final state